# How do i get all child entities in Google App Engine (Low-level API)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the low-level API in Google App Engine for Java and want to get all the child entities of a particular parent entity:

Given the following graph:

```
Parent (1)
|
+ --- Child A (2)
|    |
|    + --- Child B (3)
|
+ --- Child A (4)
```

I want a list like the following

```
[Child A (2), Child B (3), Child A (4)]
```

Here is my best attempt:

```
Entity pe = new Entity("parent");

Entity c1 = new Entity("childA", pe.getKey());
Entity c2 = new Entity("childB", c1.getKey());
Entity c3 = new Entity("childA", pe.getKey());

// storage code left out for brevity

Key parentKey = KeyFactory.createKey(null, "parent", 1);

// According to documentation this should work (but does not)
PreparedQuery q = datastore.prepare(new Query(parentKey));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that this is a known bug in the local development server.  When uploading to google it works fine

Comment: Is this a known bug? Is there a link on the bug tracker?

Comment: Were you able to find a bug fix for this issue? Because I am also developing something on GAE, and am fed up running update every few seconds!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `getKey()` be a method, not a property (`ent.getKey()`, not `ent.getKey`?

Also, isn't `parentKey` the same as `pe.getKey()`?

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the typo.

As far as pe.getKey(), I only have the Id number when the query is actually performed, so I thought I would include how I got the key.